# User is not getting update on Firbase Console after the SignUP & SignIn (React Native, Android App)(FireBase Authentication)

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I am Implementing FireBase Authentication into React Native App for the Android.

I followed the tutorial and implemented the google.json file. while `auth()                .createUserWithEmailAndPassword('xyz@gmail.com','123456')`. I am getting call back for the success and getting registered user mail from the `import auth , { FirebaseAuthTypes } from '@react-native-firebase/auth';`, but the registered and Signin user details are not showing into the FireBase console.

[image]

these two users i added manualy.

I have followed this https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage tutorial for the implementation.